# git - Recover commits that were deleted with checkout

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout

I was 2 commits ahead of Github. I did `git checkout` and these commits were deleted. I tried recover the files in .git folder to a previous version using the Dropbox history. I ran `git status` and showed that I was again 2 commits ahead, I got happy, commited and pushed to Github only to see that I didn't recover at all.

**tl;dr**: Lost 2 commits with git checkout

Comment: `git checkout` of what? a commit hash/branch/tag?

Comment: I just ran `git checkout .`

Comment: Dropbox history for git is nothing short of blasphemy :-)

Comment: @TheGeorgeous +1 for stressing that. You should say that in your anwser as well because it's too important

Answer (score 2):

Just use `git reflog` to recover the commits.

1. Run `git reflog`
2. Pick a reflog commit id that is just before the checkout
3. Run `git reset --hard commit_id_before_checkout` to get to a state just before you ran `git checkout .`